# Workflow scheduling in Informatica

Tags: workflow, informatica

My requirement is:

1. Workflow should run daily at 2pm. Workflow has been scheduled to run at 2pm
2. We have lookup on master tables. Records with IDs that are not present in the master tables will get rejected.
3. These new IDs have to be loaded into the master tables manually and then the workflow has to be re-run.
4. Daily the same thing happens.

My question is -

Is it possible to schedule a workflow to run twice every day(one for the first run, the other to run after the master table is updated)?
If No, can I manually start a scheduled workflow? Will it make the workflow unscheduled?

Please, Can any one help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Informatica's scheduler is a weak spot. I guess using two copies of the same workflow with different schedules would be the easiest solution.

Answer (score 1):

Got a solution for my problem.

Once a workflow is scheduled, even if a particular session has to be re-run manually, whole workflow has be run from the workflow manager.
If that particular session is run manually, scheduling will be gone.
So always run the workflow instead of a session, so that scheduling will remain.